# PHP Warning: html_entity_decode(): charset `UTF-8;' not supported, assuming utf-8

Tags: php, apache, opencart, opencart-3

I am getting following error when i call to html_entity_decode() to decode web URL.

My code:

```
<script>
es = new EventSource('<?php echo html_entity_decode($start); ?>');
</script>
```

Error:

> PHP Warning: html_entity_decode(): charset `UTF-8;' not supported, assuming utf-8

Php version is 7.0

Please help me to fix this issue. all answer is very helpful me

thank you

Comment: just a comment - I wouldn't mix php and js - it's bad practice

Comment: Is there an issue, because this is a warning and I suspect you can get rid of it by defining an encoding in the decode function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default for the `$encoding` parameter is `ini_get('default_charset')`, i.e. whatever is set in your php.ini or has been set at runtime using `ini_set`. You have somehow set `'UTF-8;'`. Remove the trailing `;` (either in your php.ini or wherever you `ini_set` the value).